# Tags for a FAQ section in Doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen, and I would like to create a FAQ section.

Which doxygen tags would you use to indent questions and answers?

```
/**
@section Section_FAQ Frequently Asked Questions

Question: Why is your FAQ so ugly?

Answer: We are currently working on this issue, we should use some specific doxygen tags; a question has been posted on StackOverflow.
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen allows embedding of pseudo html tags, that get converted into the selected output format. See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html
For example, you could use the classical html [definition list structure](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp):

```
<DL>
  <DT>
    Question: Why is your FAQ so ugly?
  </DT>
  <DD>
    Answer: We are currently working on this issue, we should use some specific
    doxygen tags; a question has been posted on StackOverflow.
  </DD>
</DL>
```

The final appearance can then be fine tuned using the css file. For the Latex output however, it shows up on the same line (with doxygen 1.7.5).

Comment: I just found that it's nearly what you get when using @par, the <dl> tags apart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subsection

```
@subsection SubSection_Q_UglyFAQ Why is your FAQ so ugly?

That question is now outdated. The FAQ is beautifull. The users which wonder this should update their doc.
```